# Change/map object properties to enum values

Tags: javascript, typescript

I get a data object from the backend that looks like this:

```
  data: [
            {description: 'desc', timestamp: yesterday, type: 'Repair', repair: {}},
            {description: 'desc', timestamp: oneMonthBack, type: 'Checked', readout: {}},
            {description: 'desc', timestamp: threeMonthBack, type: 'False', fault: {}},
            {description: 'desc', timestamp: yesterday, type: 'Read', falseRead: [{}]},
            {description: 'desc', timestamp: yesterday, type: 'Clear'}
          ],
```

In front-end we have changed the datas "type" via one enum:

```
export enum ProductEventType {
  FAULT = 'Alert',//Old "False"
  REPAIR = 'repair', //old 'Repair'
  DELIVERY = 'Delivery', //same as before
  CHECKIN = 'check-in', //old 'checked' 
  READFAULTS = 'readFaults',  //old Read
  CLEARFAULTS = 'ClearFaults', //old Clear
}
```

When we get the data from the backend we use a map and check every item:

```
this.vehicleEvents.data.forEach((item) => {

      if (RepairEvent.isRepairEvent(item)) {...}
```

inside the RepairEvent.isRepairEvent lies the issue, where the fault lies that we match the backend name of the data and the front-end enum name. Notice we import and use the enum type:

```
export class ClearFaultsEvent extends ProductTimelineEvent {
  public static isClearFaultsEvent(event: ProductTimelineEvent): event is ClearFaultsEvent {
    return event.type === ProductTimelineEventType.CLEARFAULTS; 

//err, event.type is 'Clear' while the enumtype have the name "ClearFaults"
      }
```

In above code we compare the backend name of the data and the name from the enum which obviously returns false, but we want true. We want the event.type somehow mapped or combined with the enum values so the conditional will works. As for now it will always be false. Any help?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wgrDyW), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: Can you explain what purpose the front end change has?  Are those new values displayed to users or something?  What do they do?  Without some compelling reason, the obvious answer is "change your `enum` back so that it matches the back end data, and if you still have some need for some different set of values in the front end, create a new data structure for it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking for this

```
const adaptType = adaptTable => f => ({type}) => f({
  type: adaptTable[type]
});

const adaptProductEvents = adaptType({
  'False': 'Alert',
  'Repair': 'repair',
  'Delivery': 'Delivery',
  'checked': 'check-in',
  'Read': 'readFaults',
  'Clear': 'ClearFaults',
});

data.map(adaptProductEvents(ClearFaultsEvent.isClearFaultsEvent))
// [ false, false, false, false, true ]
```

But it doesn't scale. A more sensible change would be to create adapter classes which would conform to the back-end API.

Now I am surprised that the values of the enum matter to you. If you need to do some IO based on the enum values, that should be the responsibility of a presenter to translate them to the correct output. You don't want business rules to know about the view.

Comment: Exactly like this! I had to put some type declaration, but it gives me an error "Binding element 'type' implicitly has an 'any' type." See link:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgEzgBygFQJ7IKYwLwwAUiK6cARgDbYBc8YGAlPgHxEBmdcDzebhAbyhZsAX15t2ggFAwYwnFySo0FagG0F2ALrTxAbmnTQkWCVQAFAE4gEAV2BQAogDdsYKBHzxl6ETLkAcgAxOEoIbEC6QIBBaisoQIAaWRhAgCVsZDgASysotKss3PyUoIARbEoctysMAsDK6tr6srTgAAtsYABrbAQGzu6egFocsGTUjOxEBqLEULtKT0mggGFqOHzojZmrReWISYNpIA

I agree the solution could have been better, but thats the way it has been implemented by two different teams unfortunately.

Comment: Made it work, had to change ({type} : {type:any}) in TS. Thanks again.